# Uploaded Image does not show in Safari 5.1 on Windows

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this tutorial](http://codepen.io/matt-west/full/CfilG) to upload Image and display it. It works well in Chrome and Firefox but it is not showing uploaded image in safari. Why?

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

<h1>Image File Reader</h1>
<div>
    Select an image file: 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
<div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;

                fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Open web development tools (Firebug for Firefox or CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome), select the image element with the element inspector and have a look at the URL that it is loading from and determine how it is different from the URL it *should* be loading from.

---

Since you're using Safari 5.1 on Windows, the FileReader API isn't supported and Safari on Windows will no longer be updated your best bet is to use a placeholder image from the server and call this battle a draw. Safari 5.1 market share on Windows is trivial at best and will only decrease as time goes on. Part of programming is knowing when to walk away from a fight.

---

```
if (window.FileReader)
{
 //Your FileReader code here.
}
else
{
 //Insert an image from the server here.
}
```

Comment: Safari has developer tools; are you using Safari on a Mac or Windows though? If Windows you can pretty much ignore it as they stopped releasing at version 5.1. If you don't see the Developer menu go to Edit --> Preferences --> Advanced and check "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

Comment: Yeah, show the develop menu. You can also press CTRL+ALT+I. Once the Web Inspector is open then at the bottom-left is a spyglass icon, click on it and then click on where the image or nearby elements are.

Comment: It does not show the uploaded image URL. It only shows the html of file upload control.

Comment: Okay then click on the 'Network' menu in the Web Inspector. If you don't see the HTTP 404 or 200 image request then there isn't even an `img` element being loaded and you'll have to dig a little deeper in to the generated code.

Comment: I just checked that if(window.FileReader) is giving me false. It means safari is not supporting FileReader.

Comment: Can you suggest alternative way to upload image and preview for Safari.

Comment: Yeah, the FileReader API isn't supported in Safari 5.1 so it is simply not going to work: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: You need to load the image from the server. Considering that lack of support will only continue to diminish you should instead use a placeholder image loaded from the server. Concentrate your efforts on browsers that DO work and versions that have CONSIDERABLE levels of market share.

Comment: Issue is not resolved. If you can provide me good alternative. I will accept it.

Comment: Appended object detection.